# Extinction of THEM

Tags: knowledge

After snowmobiles' usage had been wide spread, the one of **THEM** was mentioned to extinct.
There are about 400 of **THEM** in the world.
Who are **THEY**?

Comment: Is the grammar error in "the one of **THEM** was mentioned to extinct" intentional?

Comment: How can an extinct **THEM** number 400?

Comment: @Barker You mean errors, I guess.

Comment: THEM - means some entities. Their count is about 400. And one of this entities has been close to extinct due to snowmobiles popularity

Comment: This is not a riddle, nor a puzzle of any kind. It's a trivia question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THEY are

> Dog breeds.

After snowmobiles' usage had been wide spread, the one of THEM was mentioned to extinct.

> The numbers of Greenland's sled dogs have been decreasing rapidly due to the increasing use of snowmobiles, to the point that the breed [may be facing extinction](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6393/1080.1).

There are about 400 of THEM in the world.

> I suppose this depends on who one asks. The FCI recognizes about 340 breeds officially. However, there are plenty of breeds not officially recognized listed on Wikipedia's [list of dog breeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dog_breeds) article, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions doesn't seem to be clear.  I will offer this as an answer because it does ring a bell about something I heard about from a friend a while back.

> In some states, such as Wyoming, it is popular to use snowmobiles to kill coyotes and wolves by running them down and then running them over with the snowmobile.  This has been practiced to the extent that there are now about 50 or so Red Wolves left in the wild.  There are still quite a few Gray Wolves but their numbers are declining because of the crazy hunting practices in some of these states.

Comment: Please put answers in spoiler tags, using >!

Comment: Close. But no correct